# Flutter pub get failed when I add new package to dependencies

Tags: flutter

When I try to add flutter_audio_recorder: ^0.5.5 to the dependencies and after I push to "pub get"I face with an error like below how can I solve it can someone help me have a nice day??................................................................................................................................................................................................

### pubspec.yaml

```
name: lezzet_kitabi
description: A new Flutter application.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  bordered_text: ^1.0.1
  sqflite: ^2.0.0+2
  path_provider: ^2.0.1
  provider: ^5.0.0
  camera: 0.5.8+17
  image_picker: ^0.7.2
  path: ^1.8.0
  vibration: ^1.7.3
  holding_gesture: ^0.0.3
  flutter_audio_recorder: ^0.5.5



dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - images/logoBGopacity.png
    - images/logoBG.png
    - images/cuttedlogo.PNG
    - images/sticker0.png
    - images/sticker1.png
    - images/sticker2.png
    - images/sticker3.png
    - images/sticker4.png
    - images/sticker5.png
    - images/sticker6.png
    - images/sticker7.png
    - images/sticker8.png
    - images/sticker9.png
    - images/sticker10.png
    - images/sticker11.png
    - images/sticker12.png
    - images/sticker13.png
    - images/sticker14.png
    - images/sticker15.png
    - images/sticker16.png
    - images/sticker17.png
    - images/sticker18.png
    - images/sticker19.png
    - images/sticker20.png
    - images/sticker21.png
    - images/sticker22.png
    - images/stickerForRecipeScreen.png

  fonts:
   - family: Marck
     fonts:
       - asset: fonts/MarckScript-Regular.ttf
   - family: Graduate
     fonts:
       - asset: fonts/Graduate-Regular.ttf
   - family: OpenSans
     fonts:
        - asset: fonts/OpenSansCondensed-Light.ttf
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

### ERROR

```
Because every version of flutter_audio_recorder depends on file ^5.0.4 and process >=4.0.0 depends on file ^6.0.0, flutter_audio_recorder is incompatible with process >=4.0.0.
And because xdg_directories 0.2.0 depends on process ^4.0.0 and no versions of xdg_directories match >0.2.0 <0.3.0, flutter_audio_recorder is incompatible with xdg_directories ^0.2.0.
And because path_provider_linux 2.0.0 depends on xdg_directories ^0.2.0 and no versions of path_provider_linux match >2.0.0 <3.0.0, flutter_audio_recorder is incompatible with path_provider_linux ^2.0.0.
And because path_provider 2.0.1 depends on path_provider_linux ^2.0.0 and no versions of path_provider match >2.0.1 <3.0.0, flutter_audio_recorder is incompatible with path_provider ^2.0.1.
So, because lezzet_kitabi depends on both path_provider ^2.0.1 and flutter_audio_recorder ^0.5.5, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because lezzet_kitabi depends on both path_provider ^2.0.1 and flutter_audio_recorder ^0.5.5, version solving failed.)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your package `flutter_audio_recorder` depends on the `file` package version 5.0.4, but at the same time your `process` package depends on `file` version 6.0.0. Now since both of them are being used at the same time, one package needs the version 5.0.4 and one package need version 6.0.0 of `file` package. So due to this "clash", you are getting an error. You can read the documentation, read about the versions of other packages which are needed for their working and downgrade one of the package's version and error will be solved.

Since it is written that "every version" of `flutter_audio_recorder` depends on `file` version 5.0.4. I think you should add another package, named `process` and add a downgraded version of it, maybe 3.0.0 or something in range of 3 and it may solve your problem.

And this similar "Clashes" are happening in between other packages too. You can solve this problem by changing their versions.

I had a similar problem too a few days ago, and this thing worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jeroen-meijer.pubspec-assist

you might install the above extension for vs code and rewrite the dependencies through the extension.

the cause for the error is all your dependencies has to be depending on a similar version of other package if they have packages in common.